# Blur animation for the navigation panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, transparency

When i make the mouse over one element of the navigation panel all the navigation panel elements will be blurred except for one that the mouse is now over so i make this:

```
function hoverEffect(id) {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".blurry-text").css({
        'color': 'transparent',
        'text-shadow': '1px 1px 3px rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
    });

    $(id).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'text-shadow': '2px 2px 5px rgba(255,0,0,1)'
    });
});
```

}

and it worked, but i want to make it animated so i make this:

```
function hoverEffect(id) {

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".blurry-text").animate({
        color: 'transparent',
        textShadow: '1px 1px 3px rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
    });

    $(id).animate({
        color: 'red',
        textShadow: '2px 2px 5px rgba(255,0,0,1)'
    });
});
```

}

but it didn't work it make all the navigation elements completely transparent(i mean disappear) except for one that is selected.

so what is wrong how to make it work ?

Note: i have `jquery-1.11.3.js` and the color plug-in `jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.js` from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate the color transaction.

Comment: What do you mean @AnirbanN

Comment: provide your code here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i need to change a lot in my code to fit into JSFiddle i have a lot of external files @AnirbanN

Comment: I said in the last line note above that i already have `jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.js` so i think it will work

Comment: @BlackBlock, the fact that you can't replicate this problem in a fiddle means you have more work to do before asking a useful question on StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for pointers on creating a useful example for troubleshooting. As it stands, all we have are a couple of JS functions with no context.

Comment: I am sorry @Palpatim this question is not meant to be useful for you but, it will help me and anyone having my problem. If you have enough experience you would solve it just by the code i put here, but here we it haven't been solved yet. BTW: it's not  about knowing how to use fiddle or not it's about having to modify a lot of my code to fit into fiddle.